# RuntimeException - Exhausted Resultset - How can it happen?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, resultset

Code:

```
    // Start the query.
    final ResultSet r = prepared.executeQuery();
    try {
      // Returning false from oneRow will stop the process.
      boolean goOn = true;
      while (r.next() && goOn) {
        log.trace("Result: {}", toString(r));
        // We did do at least one.
        ran = true;
        goOn = oneRow(r);
      }
    } finally {
      try {
        // Always remember to close the ResultSet.
        r.close();
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
        log.error("Close failed", ex);
      }
    }

    // Handle one row.
    public boolean oneRow(ResultSet r) throws Exception {
      String xml1 = r.getString(1);
      String xml2 = r.getString(2);
      if (xml1 == null && xml2 == null) {
        // Probably compressed.
        xml1 = decompress(r, 3);
        xml2 = decompress(r, 4);
      }
      return false;
    }

  private static String decompress(ResultSet rs, int col) throws SQLException {
    // Exception gets thrown here!!! ???
    final InputStream compressed = rs.getBinaryStream(col);
    ...
```

As you can see this is not the obvious problem of not calling `ResultSet.next()`. Not only that but I have called `getString` in the `ResultSet` twice already, it is the third time that breaks it.

Note that this is an occasional issue, this code works fine most of the time.

The query looks something like:

```
"SELECT P1.XML XML1, "
      + "P2.XML XML2, "
      + "P1.CompressedXML CompressedXML1, "
      + "P2.CompressedXML CompressedXML2 "
      + "FROM Table1 P1 "
      + "LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.ID = P1.ID "
      + "LEFT JOIN Table1 P2 ON P2.ID = T2.Item_Code "
      + "WHERE P1.ID = ?"
```

I realise this is a rather incestuous query but as I stated - this all works fine most of the time.

**Added**

Prompted by the answer posted by `user1933888` it occurs to me that since I am using a home-grown connection-pool is it possible for a prepared statement to interfere with itself between two threads sharing different connections?

I am confident that the same connection will never be in use by two threads at the same time but the prepared statement could be shared as it should reside in the database.

Comment: that might be some data issue

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: Note also, oneRow always returns false, so you would never process more than one row, is that intended?

Comment: @beny23 - In this case yes - this particular use of my `Query` class is a simple look-up in the database of details a product. I only want the first result.

Comment: Then you could replace while with if and wouldn't need goOn. I'd also look into adding conditions to tell the db to only return the first row to avoid unnecessary data coming back from the db.

Comment: Re your edit: do your threads share the PreparedStatement object? That would be a problem.

Comment: @beny23 - This is a general `Query` class that can be used for a one-shot look-up as well as a multi-result query. Generally the query itself will determine whether to expect one result or many and the user will return true/false as appropriate. Are you suggesting that a premature close of the `ResultSet` could trigger my issue?

Comment: @beny23 - I have made no effort to ensure prepared statements are not shared between threads - I understand they normally end up in the DBMS so they should be shared by multiple threads - or have I got that wrong.

Comment: @beny23 - Sorry - I will not have access to the stack trace until Monday. Thank you for your interest. I do recall that the exception is thrown from within the Oracle driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your PreparedStatement is linked to a connection, if you share the PreparedStatement between threads you would end up sharing a connection and that definitely will cause problems.

It is true that statements are generally cached in the DB to avoid having to reparse it but you'd still need one PreparedStatement object per thread to avoid confusing the DB driver as to what thread wants what.

In general, I would avoid a home brew connection pool considering that in general AppServers do the pooling for you or (if you're not in an AppServer) there are plenty of connection pool libs out there, so why reinvent the wheel.

In general:

- you can shared DataSources between concurrent threads
- you should NOT share Connection, PreparedStatement or ResultSet objects between concurrent threads

The connection pool will ensure that non-concurrent threads can reuse Connections and the JDBC driver will internally cache Statements

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I am sure I came across a post on another site (perhaps JavaLobby but I cannot find it now) that suggests that prepared statements are stored in the DBMS and are therefore accessible from any thread/connection once they have been created - essentially they persist as a plan of some form. I would be happy to be corrected on that.

Comment: +1 - I agree about the home-brew connection pool - this is inherited code and I am in the process of switching it to a proper pool.

Comment: ... *perhaps JavaLobby* ... it was certainly [JavaRanch](http://www.javaranch.com/) but I still cannot find the reference.

Comment: Think of it that way: a PreparedStatement is linked to one connection (the one from which you called prepareStatement from). If you use that in concurrent threads, you'd be using the same connection at the same time, which is going to lead to trouble.

Comment: Some very detailed examination of the logs shows some strange cross-poisoning of prepared statements. Essentially statements prepared on one connection seem to occasionally poison the same statement on another connection on another thread. To combat this I am going to close all prepared statements after use and use a tested connection pool (c3p0). Hopefully this will clear my issue.